# Detecting and validating client date change in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, momentjs

In my Angularjs application I have the limitation that if user changes his system date manually, application starts using that date for all UI operations.

I want to detect if user has changed his system date manually to some older date and compare it with server date stored in my cookies and throw him an error.
I tried using :

```
$window.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
   alert('I changed');
});
```

but this didn't worked.
Is there a way in Angular to do this.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367505/detecting-changes-to-system-time-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger timeupdate event with using of jQuery.

```
$('#testvid').on('timeupdate', function(){
    console.log('the time was updated to: ' + this.currentTime);
});
```

Here `#testvid` is id of html element.

Comment: timeupdate is an event which i found here [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you can use `setInterval` to check for date change at certain intervals of time. It can be done in Angular like below:

```
var app = angular.module('dateChecker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {

  function getTodaysDate(){
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
    } 

    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
    } 

    today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
    return today;
  }

  $scope.oldDate = getTodaysDate();

  $interval(function dateChecker() {
    if($scope.oldDate === getTodaysDate()){
        console.log('No change');
    } else {
        console.log('date changed');
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

This checks the time every second and updates accordingly. 
I'm checking only the `date` above ignoring the time, you can change the condition as required.